# Definition of the spectrum in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-languages, formal-proofs

I want to understand the definition of the spectrum and therefore I want to know, what it means that a model has n elements or that a model is of size n. 
What is said to be an element? Are these only the elements of the universe?

Furthermore, I am trying to find a sentence $\phi$ without any "="-relation, so that $sp(\phi) = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: n > 5\}$. Any idea on that?